# How to bundle a JAR file into a Mac Application Bundle

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar, export

I have looked around but I cannot find anything that will help or work. I know there is Launch4j which will do what I want with an .exe but not a .app file. I have the runnable JAR but do not know how to bundle it into a .app. I have tried multiple times (with no success) to export it as a .app from eclipse but it will not open after it is exported; no error message it just will not open. So my question is how can I bundle this into an Application Bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Java 6 or lower and an older System, then you have a Program made by Apple (I think) in the Developer directory. This does exactly what you want, otherwise, you could create a "hack" Application bundle (because it's the "I don't want to search through the internet" method).

1. start Script Editor
2. klick on "Save As" and under "File" select "Application".
3. right klick on the Bundle and select "Show Package Contents"
4. navigate to "Contents/MacOS" and delete the file "applet"
5. create a new file with the same name and paste the following code into it:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   SOURCE="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
   while [ -h "$SOURCE" ]; do
       DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"
       SOURCE="$(readlink "$SOURCE")"
       [[ $SOURCE != /* ]] && SOURCE="$DIR/$SOURCE"
   done
   DIR="$( cd -P "$( dirname "$SOURCE" )" && pwd )"

   cd "$DIR"
   cd ..

   echo "$(pwd)"

   for file in *
   do
       if [ -f "$file" ]
       then
           if [[ "$file" =~ .*.jar ]]
           then
               java -jar "$file"
           fi
       fi
   done
   ```
6. save the file
7. now open terminal (Spotlight -> Terminal)
   and type the following `chmod 755`  note the space behind the 755. Then drag the file you just created into the Terminal window at the end of the text you just typed and hit enter.
8. the last thing to do is to copy the jar file into the "Contents" folder.

Note: You are creating a Default AppleScript Applet and then switch the executable with your own in order to be able to launch the jar file. To give it execute permission you need to do the `chmod 755`.

This is how it should look:
[image: -]

Comment: I followed these steps exactly but it gives the error "This file cannot be opened because it is incomplete"

Comment: Did you really name the file applet? With no extension? Because thats the only reason I can think of that might be causing this error. I included a screenshot of how the file hierarchy should look like.

Comment: Can you maybe accept my answer, if its what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes my bad. Do you know how I would bundle the JRE with this app?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you would need to do this, since a lot of people have it, but if you are desperate (really desperate, I think java has about 350 MB), you could run `/usr/libexec/java_home` to get your java home and then drop it in the app bundle, then you just need to modify the bash script to use this java install.

Comment: Do I just need the home folder? And does that go in resources, MacOS, or just the bundle?

Comment: I don't know which files are needed by java, so I would recommend copying the whole folder into the Contents folder. Then replace `java -jar "$file"` with the following line: `./Home/bin/java -jar "$file"`